# 11gR2 didn't ask me to set username or any password

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, installation

I have installed Oracle 11gR2 (latest version 11.2.0.1.0) on my system. During the installation it didn't ask me to set username or any password. I'm unable to start sql plus because i don't have the username and password.
Can anyone tell me what is the default username and password or what is the default password for SYS or SYSTEM?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the Universal Installer included with 11gR2 did not ask for a password, it is likely that the option to create a database was not selected during installation.

Solution? Create a database with the `dbca` tool and supply a sys password when prompted.

With older versions, perhaps including Oracle Database XE (11g), you might have luck with one of the default password combinations of sys/change_on_install or system/welcome1 or system/manager. On engineered systems I have also seen sys/welcome1 and sys/changeme

Answer (score -1):

if you have administrator permission, after entering "sqlplus sys as sysdba" command press the enter. and press the Enter again for password will let you query the database ! and then you can change the password for sys from $ Tables.
hope this help

Comment: This depends on internal authentication, which may or may not be applicable. Password for sys is set with "alter user sys identified by password".